# HTML Radio Button GroupName Property

Tags: html, radio-button, radio-group

Can we make a group of radio button without using name attribute??

In my code . I am already using name attribute to fetch the data from view by providing it unique name and name attribute should be same to group some radio buttons.

So, that's why I am asking that is there any another way to group them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other way to group radio buttons is just to literally group them:

```
<form>
    <div id="group1">
        <input type="radio">Option 1
        <input type="radio">Option 2
    </div>
    <div id="group2">
        <input type="radio">Option 3
        <input type="radio">Option 4
    </div>
</form>
```

Then navigate through the IDs with your processor, using `checked` to get the currently checked radio.